# Getting CORS headers in a Flask 500 error

Tags: flask-cors

I've got a Flask app set up like this

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.cors import CORS

app = Flask( . . . )
app.debug = True

CORS(app, allow_headers='Content-Type')
```

CORS works correctly for routes that complete properly. However, if an exception is raised, the debug output is generated without CORS headers. This means I cannot see the debug output in chrome. Can I fix this?

Answer (score 9):

The issue has to do with setting debug mode. You can see the discussion about this in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors/issues/67).

There are two ways you could get around this. The easiest is to set the `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` configuration parameter to `False`, but this deprives you of the debug-mode stack trace page:

```
app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = False
```

The second would be to write your own exception handler. I haven't tried this myself, but the [flask source](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/915d34444b2a1be982940e6f3c91576adc8aa57f/flask/app.py#L1526-L1553) can give you guidance.